# "defense-aviation" vs. "military" tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed we have 13 questions tagged with [defense-aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defense-aviation). Is there a way this could be differentiated from [military](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military) or can we get rid of that tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That tag does not make sense to me. I have never heard of the term "Defense Aviation" used anywhere.

I suggest we change them to [military](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military).